Is AC power in India unstable?
I often feel electricity from the chargers I use in India.
I think it is because the building is not grounded. Do most people have similar experiences?
What should I consider in my design to solve this problem?

Home Improvement might be better suited for these kinds of questions. EE is more focussed on electronics design.

What chargers? phone ones? Ebike? provide details please.

The reason is given in this Q&A: Feeling a tingling sensation by touching stuff, Is this safe?

India is the 7th largest country by area - is it reasonable to make a generalized statement about the voltage supply quality of the whole nation?

I often feel electricity from the chargers I use in India. That's because these USB chargers are cheap and have significant leakage current. You can take them anywhere else in the world and you will feel the same. Unfortunately, the only assurance of reasonably designed chargers is to buy them from recognized brand sources, paying close attention not to treat fakes as the real thing. Among many, Samsung, Apple, Huawei, IKEA, and Clas Ohlson branded chargers are trustworthy and are consistently shown to be high-quality designs. The first three are also most likely to be faked, unfortunately.

Ground has nothing to do with it. Poor design is the answer.

@Dereck Not true. Your chargers or devices may expect to be connected to earthed socket. If you can't provide one, your mains inlet filtet makes sure everything that should be earthed will give you a sting. That's not poor design, just user error of using earth-needing devices without earth.

Many chargers (such as AC to USB or laptop power supplies) don’t use an earth connection at all, especially those designed to be used in places where 2-pin AC outlets are common.  Many US plugs, for example, have symmetrical plugs so it’s impossible to differentiate ‘live’ and ‘neutral’, if one wanted to assume that there’s little difference in voltage between neutral and earth.
So non-earthed chargers aim to generate minimal leakage current, which should be imperceptible under normal conditions.
A couple of possibilities are that (a) you have devices with high earth leakage, or (b) you have earthed devices but there’s a significant voltage difference between the earth pins of your sockets and your local ‘true’ earth, which could happen if nearby devices have a significant leakage current to earth.  My limited knowledge of electrical installation work in India suggests that this may not be uncommon.

Don't US plugs come in both polarized and unpolarized? Can you generalize that they are all symmetrical/unpolarized?

@Justme I’ve edited my answer accordingly

The outlets are not symmetrical in any standard-compliant US installation. Maybe you mean many devices have symmetrical plugs?

@Hearth also noted.
